# How do I get all recent instagram media by a user?

Tags: instagram, instasharp

I am using **InstaSharp** to try and get a user's latest media posts. I am getting error:

```
{"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."}
```

Here is my code:

```
    public async Task<string> GetUserRecentMedia(string userId)
    {
        string response = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            InstagramConfig config = new InstagramConfig(ClientId, ClientSecret, RedirectUri, string.Empty);
            Users usersEndpoints = new Users(config);
            response = ConvertToJson(usersEndpoints.Recent(userId));
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: ***Kind of exception*** ?

Comment: did you use `await` ? any final _sample code_ about it ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to call InstaSharp methods in async methods (as you have done) And await
the method you want to call so

```
await usersEndpoints.Recent(userId);
```